# Java double scaling

Tags: java

If I have a double in the range of x - y, how can I scale this double to the new range a - b

For example converting from -1 -> 1 to 0 -> 1

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
 * @param value The incoming value to be converted
 * @param low1  Lower bound of the value's current range
 * @param high1 Upper bound of the value's current range
 * @param low2  Lower bound of the value's target range
 * @param high2 Upper bound of the value's target range
 */
public static final double map(double value, double low1, double high1, double low2, double high2) {

    double diff = value - low1;
    double proportion = diff / (high1 - low1);

    return lerp(low2, high2, proportion);
}

// Linearly interpolate between two values
public static final double lerp(double value1, double value2, double amt) {
    return ((value2 - value1) * amt) + value1;
}
```

http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/useful-utility-functions-0-of-n/

In your case you would call `map(x, -1, 1, 0, 1)`

Comment: +1 for introducing me to `lerp`. You have made my day. :) Please change 3rd parameter name to `scale`.